# Google Calendar quickstart.py doesn't get upcoming 10 events

Tags: google-calendar-api

I successfully work through this tutorial: [Python quickstart | Google Calendar | Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python). However I don't get the upcoming 10 events. How should I debug this?

Comment: Hi, are you getting a specific error when running `quickstart.py`?

Comment: No error, just not the expected result, and I don't know how to quarantine the problem

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the upcoming 10 events`. Can I ask you about the details of it and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: the purpose of the `quickstart.py` script is to query 10 events on your Google Calendar, whose time is larger than now, and sort by start time. That is effectively listing 10 nearest future events. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line 46 of the script:

```py
            calendarId="primary",
```

You need to fill in the correct calendar ID. The ID is in the Integrate calendar section of your calendar's setting:

[image]

For more information, look at [Primary calendars & other calendars](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#primary_calendars_other_calendars) from the API documentation.